# Vue, TypeScript, multi-file component, image not getting processed

Tags: image, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I implemented a multi-file component setup:

```
src/components/ui/navbar/
    Navbar.component.ts
    navbar.html
    navbar.scss
```

With-in the navbar.html I had a `<img />` used which was getting base64'd up to the point I externalized it in a multi-file component.

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
    <router-link tag="a" to="/home" class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="CompanyName">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/logo.png" alt="CompanyName">
    </router-link>
</div>
```

I looked in the `dist/` folder and I'm not seeing the logo.png.
I reviewed the final output and the image is no longer base64'd or copied.

I suspect there is something needed in the `vue.config.js` to inform Webpack of a multi-file component (like Angular) but I am not finding anything about it online.

I will copy in the config I have now with some things commented out as I tested.

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
      config
        .output
        .filename("[name].[hash].js")
        .end();
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
        .rule("vue")
        .use("vue-svg-inline-loader")
            .loader("vue-svg-inline-loader")
            .options({ /* ... */ });
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          exclude: /index.html/,
          loader: "vue-template-loader",
          options: {
            transformToRequire: {
              // The key should be element name,
              // the value should be attribute name or its array
              img: "src",
            },
          },
          test: /.html$/,
        },
        /*{
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]?[hash]",
          },
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        },*/
        /*{
          test: /\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "svg-inline-loader",
              options: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: "assets/img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]",
              },
            },
          ],
        },*/
      ],
    },
  },
  publicPath: "/",
};
```

I've since done a CSS workaround to embed the graphic that way, but if someone has a Webpack/Vue.config.js tip I'd appreciate it.

I've attempted ../../, ../, ./ and combinations of @/ and ~/ and ~@/ before the image.

Answer (score 0):

For now I worked around the issue using `<img class="img-fluid" :src="require('@/assets/logo.png')" alt="CompanyLogo">`.

Comment: this is exactly how the documentation says to do it